# Is there a way to stop function overriding in Tcl/ itcl?

Tags: tcl

I have the following use case...

```
itcl::class A {

    public method Foo {} {}
}

itcl::class B {
    inherit A

    public method Foo {} {} // Should not be allowed

}
```

Is there a way to stop function overriding in Tcl/ itcl?

Comment: Welcome! Can you be more specific what your intentions and expectations are? Why do you want to prevent subclasses from overriding superclass-provided methods? Do you want the restriction to be enforced upon defining subclass `B` or upon calling on an instance of subclass `B`?

Comment: @mrcalvin . Yes I want to prevent subclasses from overriding few methods in base class. Something similar to using keyword final in JAVA/C++

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that itcl can do that at all. TclOO in 8.7 will be *sort-of* able to do it (by making the method on the superclass be private) but you won't be able to call it from other classes either; if a subclass can see it, it can also override it. The general principle is that if user code wishes to cause trouble, it can; it will cause itself trouble in the process, but that's how the language works: after all, you can also override built-in commands like `set` and `if` and `proc`, and that can cause a lot more mischief.

Remember, in Tcl the visibility of methods is not a security mechanism. Security mechanisms are all always tied to interpreters.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: I've just realised that there's another sort-of way to do it in TclOO (which is much more convenient in 8.7); you can use the definition language update mechanism to override `method` and `forward` so that they search for superclass methods with the same name. Except that that is eminently defeatable; it'd still be _at best_ a suggestion.